# RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 2008.17 MiB

Tags: git, macos, ionic2, cocoapods

I was trying to install cocoapodsusing `>pod setup` and it throws the following error

> tests-Mac-mini:brandz test$ pod setup
>
> Setting up CocoaPods master repo
>
> $ /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master
>   --progress
>
> Cloning into 'master'...
>
> remote: Counting objects: 1526805, done.
>
> remote: Compressing objects: 100% (517/517), done.
>
> error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 2008.17 MiB | 402.00 KiB/s
>
> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>
> fatal: early EOF
>
> fatal: index-pack failed

Is this possible to resolve this issue?

Comment: Try [this solution](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5592) from CocoaPods GitHub Issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had the some error minutes ago, then I tried another like four or five times it works fine. I think is the network problem or the file size is too large.